# Change Customer Information field in AgentTicketZoom OTRS6

Tags: perl, otrs

I want to change few fields of customer Information table of AgentTicketZoom file of OTRS6. How to do this? Is there any way?

I need to add a TicketLicense input box below LastName of the field

[Yellow circle displays where I need to add my input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1wvT.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at files:

```
Kernel/Output/HTML/Templates/Standard/AdminCustomerTableView.tt

Kernel/Output/HTML/Layout/Ticket.pm
```

You also may need to change mappings, take a look at `Kernel/Config/Defaults.pm`

Usefull link https://blog.otrs.com/2017/10/25/otrs-6-dynamic-fields-customer-user/

Answer (score 0):

If your source of customer information is a different database or an LDAP source, it would be enough to add a field in the `map` section.